# How to deal with gocloudly popup malware

Tags: 16.04, firefox, malware

Recently I'm experiencing a problem on my Ubuntu PC. Sometimes a popup window is opening which points to this address `gocloudly.com/goac/index.html`. I searched about it and most websites has mentioned it as male-ware or virus.

Unfortunately all solutions are for windows to remove it. I didn't find any Ubuntu user affected by it. Is there solution to remove this male-ware? Or maybe you have other information.

Comment: Check your Chrome or Chromium extras. It should be there. Consider reseting the browser to the defaults. However, as soon as you loging with a Google account everything will be synced again, including any malware you did catch while using Chrome in Windows.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Same principle applies. What I've found mentions Chrome though.